# How to install tqdm on a linux server without internet access?

Tags: python-2.7, tqdm

I am trying to install the python package [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) on a linux server.
However, the said server has no internet access. Hence, I am unable to install it using pip. I am also unable to find the tqdm package in [Debian's package index](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python/).

However, what I am able to do is scp files from my local machine to the server. My local has full internet and sudo access.

Any leads please?

Note: I have sudo access on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install it with `pip`. Just use the available commandline options as follows:

```
pip --no-index --find-links /path/to/directory/with/egg tqdm
```

Documentation:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#no-index
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#find-links

Comment: Thanks, that helped.